# how to send email with smtp.js use react.js

Tags: reactjs, smtp

this code inside fuction but not working
`Email.send({ Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com", Username : "username", Password : "password", To : 'them@website.com', From : "you@isp.com", Subject : "This is the subject", Body : "And this is the body" }).then( message => alert(message) );`

And
Where should I put this?

`<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"> </script>`

I put it in jsx file but it gives this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn1vY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step 1:

  ```bash
  npm install smtp.js
  ```
- Step 2:

  ```js
  import smtp from 'smtp.js';
  const credentials = {
    host: 'smtp.host.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
      user: 'username',
      pass: 'password'
    }
  }

  smtp.connect(credentials)
    .then(info => {
      // connected, credentials OK 
    }
  )
  ```
- Step 3:

  ```js
  const email = {
    from: 'sender@mail.com',
    to: 'recipient@mail.com',
    subject: 'test subject',
    html: '<p>This is an <strong>HTML email</strong></p>'
  }

  smtp.connect(credentials)
    .then(() => smtp.sendMail(email))
    .then(info => console.log('Email sent!'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  ```